# Search image for a certain colour and return the coordinates of blocks of that colour

Tags: python-2.7

Is there any library/program available in Python 2.7 that enables me to do this? I am a beginner in Python and I have to write a program that has to scan through a huge amount of images and detect all the position of a specified colour. I wonder is there any simple way to do this in Python?

Answer (score -1):

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('example.png')

pixels_count = 0

for x in xrange(img.size[0]):
    for y in xrange(img.size[1]):
        if img.getpixel((x, y)) == (255, 255, 255):
            pixels_count += 1

print pixels_count
```